# How to get module working in both Node and browser without transpiler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, es6-modules

Now that Chrome supports `import`/`export` I thought we could share some code between Node.js and browser *without* the need for Babel, but because `export` can't be wrapped in a conditional, I'm not sure how we can do this.

e.g. is there some way to write something like this

```
if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.hasOwnProperty("exports")) {
    module.exports = BigInt;
} else {
    export default BigInt;
}
```

and trick both the Chrome and Node into parsing it?

Comment: Many will use `require()` with a packager like webpack or maybe bower that packages code into something that will then run in the browser.  For example, it looks like that's what [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) does.